# How/where to add classpath entries in glassfish3.1.2.2 for an ADF Web application

Tags: java, glassfish-3, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have developed an ADF Web application using jdeveloper11.1.2.4. For ViewController project I have added one folder(PassChange) in Libraries And Classpath section as show in the below image.

[image]

I have a BSFNTest.java in ViewController project. If I run BSFNTest.java After adding (PassChange) folder in classpath this class gives correct ouptut. If I run this program after removing (PassChange) folder from classpaht BSFNTest.java throws an Exception.

PassChange - Contains some txt files that are required for BSFNTest.java to run.

BSFNTest.java program is running successfully in jdeveloper11.1.2.4 and giving correct output.

I have deployed this ADF application onto glassfish3.1.2.2. Everything is working fine. If I try to run this program on server trowing some exception because (PassChange) folder is not availabe in classpath.

Please tell me where to add this folder (PassChnage) in glassfish.

Or if you know how to deploy my application that contains (PassChange) folder in its classpath please tell me.

Thank you. If you have any queries please let me know.

EDIT: I am using Java dynamic connector. By using this am calling JDEdwards Business funtions. some txt files are required for Java Dynamic Connectory to run. I have included these txt file in jdeveloper in Classpath And Libraries section. I don't know where to place these files in glassfish. In Glassfish logs I am getting the below exception.

```
[#|2015-07-30T11:24:52.112+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.InvalidConfigurationException: enterpriseServer property not found in the INI file
    at com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.Connector.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.Connector.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.Connector.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.wipro.view.service.BSFNTest.bsfnTest_Method(BSFNTest.java:27)
    at com.wipro.view.backing.ChangePass.changePass(ChangePass.java:138)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that your JARs/Libraries are included in the file groups that make up your JDeveloper deployment profile at the application level.